# Imprimir carácteres griegos en reportes PDF desde MySql

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

necesito imprimir carácteres griegos desde mi BD, en reportes PDF lo que sucede es que solo se imprimen signos de interrogación en vez de los caracteres griegos, la BD tiene el charset utf8, el PDF utf-8, la conexión a la BD tiene utf8 pero aún así me arroja los signos de interrogación como podría solucionar este problema

Comment: Segun leo por ahí el problema parece estar relacionado con el fuente usado, prueba cambiando el fuente helvetica por dejavusans

Comment: Está repetida en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/533505/como-imprimir-caracteres-griegos-desde-mysql-a-pdf-con-tcpdf/ Por favor, no repitamos la misma pregunta a las pocas horas de formularla. Y todavía menos si como en este caso ofreces menos información

Comment: @VFG tiene razón esta repetida y además tiene el mismo nombre de usuario.

Comment: Dos cosas: 1. ¿Si muestras los datos **en pantalla** sí se ven los caracteres griegos? Si se ven, 2. Escribe un `SHOW CREATE TABLE laTabla;` donde `laTabla` es la tabla en cuestión y agrega el resultado a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].